# How can I allow a Weather Api through Google Chrome's Content Security Policy?

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, weather-api

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension similar to Momentum, where weather is displayed through an API. Here, forecast.io is being used.

I'm having trouble with displaying the weather due to the Content Security Policy in chrome.

Here's the error:

> jquery.min.js:4 Refused to load the script
>   'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/**APIKEY**/**LOCATION**…units=si&callback=jQuery31009807237261119963_1474254572792&_=1474254572793' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com".

I know it has something to do with the Policy blocking it, but how should I go about unblocking it?

Ive tried this in my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Linkage",
    "description": "A new tab page.",
    "version": "0.8",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "index.html"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com;  object-src 'self';",
    "permissions": [
        "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"
    ]
}
```

So, I've tried putting the API website in permissions like brought up in some other answers, however as seen in the error, this doesn't work.

So, again, how should I go about unblocking it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, your content_security_policy doesn't include the forecast domain. And you need to add * after / in permissions.

Comment: How do I add more than one domain on the content security policy?

Comment: Ive figured it out, just put a space after the other domain and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @dirranbolt You should post a self-answer so that this question is, in fact, answered. This may help others.